# jQuery Disable Submit -- AND Post Value?

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I'm using the jQuery disable submit method to prevent double posts of my form data.  BUT I also want the value of the submit button to be posted, which this method is preventing.  Is there any way around this?  Some of my forms have multiple submit buttons that determine how the post data is handled.  Ideas?

```
$('form').submit(function(){
     $(this).find('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled',true);
});
```

EDIT:

This counting method has been recommended, but does not seem to work for blocking submits at all.

```
var i=0;
$('form').submit(function(){
     //$(this).find('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled',true);
     i++;
     if(i>1){return false;}
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be mildly convoluted, but it seems to work.  Create a hidden input on the fly that has the same name and value as the submit button you just clicked:

```
$('input[type="submit"]').click(function(){
   var thisname = $(this).attr('name');
   var thisval = $(this).val();
   $('<input>').attr({
    type: 'hidden',
    name: thisname,
    value: thisval
   }).appendTo('form');

});

$('form').submit(function(){
  $(this).find('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled',true);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

On form submit set a variable like isSubmitting to true. If the user clicks submit again (either via the button or hitting enter while the form is active) it won't submit because you check this variable.

Note that this is better than just disabling the button as there's more than one way to double-post the form.

Comment: You can combine this with setting the opacity of the button to .5 or something to indicate that it is not usable.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('form').submit(function(){
     $(this).find('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled',true);
     return true;
});
```

Actutally this should work. As explained here too: http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/05/disable-submit-button-on-form-submit.html

Comment: @swf: i believe you have some other problems then

Comment: I think you misunderstood his question.  A disabled input does not send a value to the backend.  He wants the value from the input to still get passed to the backend but the button to not be clickable.

Comment: @king: acutally it does send for me. Maybe because I am using a `<button type="submit">` ?

Comment: That could be, I haven't tried this exactly, but I do know that other types of input (checkbox, etc.) will not send if disabled.